# Any way to know if your drone was shot down in CSGO: Danger Zone?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When you're waiting for a drone to deliver a purchased item CSGO: Danger Zone, is there any way to know if someone's shot it down and stolen your item? I'm fairly sure this happened to me earlier, but I didn't notice any indication. Eventually I just stopped waiting for it. It's possible I missed it.

**Is there any audio or visual indicator that your drone was shot down?**

I know I could track it on an upgraded tablet, but is there any other way to tell?

Comment: Please accept my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain a tablet upgrade either on the floor or purchase via the tablet itself that tells you updates on the drone. With this, you will know if your drone is shot down, but otherwise, you can just assume it is shot down if it doesn't come for a while.